# How do I modify my .htaccess file to redirect a URL for one domain only, and not rewrite other domains hosted by the same server

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, movabletype

I switched blogging software (MT to WordPress) on a site and need to redirect requests to http://www.domain1/atom.xml to http://www.domain1.com/feed/atom.

I was using a simple Redirectmatch rule, but realized that it was also redirecting requests made to another site (domain2), that is is hosted by the server, in a subdirectory of domain1, which I do not want to happen (its feed is still at http://www.domain2.com/atom.xml).

How do I get the redirect to only occur for domain1?

I was trying to do the following, but it didn't work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/atom\.xml$  http://www.domain1.com/feed/atom [L,R=301]
```

Am I close?

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 0):

If you don't do any rewriting for domain2 then a quick fix would be to create a `.htaccess` file inside its root folder and disable rewriting with `RewriteEngine off`.

Otherwise you are on the right path with the `RewriteCond`, it should do the trick. Have you tried adding `$` at the end (`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com$ [NC]`) / any misspelling / `www.` vs no `www.`?

Comment: Yes, I had tried those variations before, but just tried them again to double check...still not working. - Rich

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, but I'm not sure why exactly this works. I moved my .htaccess to be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^atom\.xml$  http://www.domain1.com/feed/atom [L,R=301]
```

I removed the slash in front of "atom" in the RewriteRule.

I would think I should have the slash, as I'm tyring to redirect http://www.domain1.com/atom.xml .

It's at the root of the domain...

Oh well. Can anyone explain why this works? Is the string passed to the pattern matching not contain the starting slash?

Thanks,
Rich

Comment: Good catch. Indeed the first slash is not contained in the matched string.